# socket.io error objects sent from server don't have message property on client

Tags: node.js, error-handling, socket.io

I have an error-handling piece of code which filters errors into my pre-defined custom error objects such as `InvalidJWTError` object. These objects always have the `name, message, status` properties.

When an error occurs in my socket.io event handler body, I catch it with a `try-catch` block and then emit the error with my `error` event which is only sending the occured and filtered error object to client. The implementation is shown below:

```js
// Server implementation:
io.on('connection', socket =>
    ...
    socket.on('authenticated', async token => {
        // Providing invalid token manually to cause
        // InvalidJWTError and catch it then send it to client
        token = 'nope';
        socket.handshake.auth.token = token;

        try {
            const userDTO = await services.userService.authenticate(token);
            socket.data.user = userDTO;
        } catch(error) {
            // Thrown error object:
            // InvalidJWTError: Invalid JWT provided.
            // ... (stack trace)
            // status: 401
            socket.emit('error', ErrorHandler.handle(error));
        }
    });
    ...
});
```

```js
// Client implementation:
socket.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
    // Outputs:
    // { name: "InvalidJWTError", status: 401 }
    // There has to be a message property with
    // value "Invaldi JWT provided."
});
```

As explained in the code comments, the message property of error object doesn't show up in client, and client doesn't view the object as a Error instance. The client just says the received error object is only an Object, not an instance of Error. Why does socket.io behave this way?

Things I've tried:

- Rather than using my custom error classes, I tried to instantiate a regular Error object like `new Error('Something went wrong!')` but this object still shows up as a instance of Object, not Error class, and message property is still missing on client. Resutling in an input simply `{}` since the only property is message and it's missing this is the result. (?? Really??)
- Tried changing event name "error" to something else like "errorOccured"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.emit()` takes your Error object and serializes it to JSON.  Here are some things to know about the JSON format and `JSON.stringify()`:

1. JSON contains no provisions at all for recording what class an object instance is.  It just treats all objects (no matter what class) as a plain Javascript object.  Thus, the recipient will have no idea at all what class the object originally was unless you manually set a property on the object that identifies its class and then convert it into an instance of that class when you receive it.  Keep in mind that classes are a local concept.  In Javascript a class name corresponds to a local constructor and thus a class name on a server may have no corresponding definition on a client.  Further, JSON is a language independent data interchange format and thus a class in Javascript on the server may not be relevant at all to a client using a completely different language.  As such, JSON does not support the concept of an object's class.  It's just not in the definition of what JSON is or does.
2. `JSON.stringify()` only serializes enumerable properties.  That means it will not serialize all properties of an Error object, only the enumerable ones.  You can work around this by creating your own object and assigning the Error object properties you want to send as plain properties (which, by default, will be enumerable).

> I tried to instantiate a regular Error object like new Error('Something went wrong!') but this object still shows up as a instance of Object, not Error class

This is because of point #1 above.

> Resulting in an input simply {} since the only property is message and it's missing this is the result.

This is because of point #2 above.  Even the `message` property is not enumerable and thus none of the default properties of an Error object will serialize with `JSON.stringify()`.

You can see this yourself by running this code:

```
const err = new Error("This is the message");

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(err));
```

Which shows this output:

```
{
  stack: {
    value: 'Error: This is the message\n' +
      '    at Object.<anonymous> (...temp.js:1:13)\n' +
      '    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)\n' +
      '    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)\n' +
      '    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)\n' +
      '    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)\n' +
      '    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)\n' +
      '    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47',
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  },
  message: {
    value: 'This is the message',
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  }
}
```

And, you will notice that both these properties are `enumerable: false`, thus `JSON.stringify()` will skip them.

---

This additional comment has nothing to do with your problem, but I would generally not choose to send an `error` event from server to client or client to server.  The `error` event is already used for clients and servers to communicate errors that happened locally to your code locally.  Sending an `error` event from client to server or vice versa will likely confuse code that is watching for local errors.

It's better to just define your own event name that is unique and not used by the socket.io infrastructure itself.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! In socket.io documentation I haven't a disallowed event named "error" so I thought it would be quite descriptive to use that name "error" to send and receive errors. But I will still change the name to something like "errorOccured". I think I will also send only the message property of errors caught since socket.io is not an HTTP protocol, sending status codes for such errors is not meaningful, sending name of the error doesn't have much application uses too. So this way I think I will be fine. What do you think?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN - It's not prohibited to use the `error` event for sending errors, but it makes your own coding more complicated - that's why I recommend avoiding it.  Http status codes are standard so if you're trying to communicate an error in a standard way, http status codes can still work just fine even though it's not http.  But, if you just want to display an error to the user (not acted on by code), then a message works fine as long as you know how you will translate that message into different languages in the client should your app want to be operable in different languages.